# Playing specific audio file for each cell row

Tags: objective-c, audio, avfoundation, uitableview

I am beginner and currently working with a table view. I've populated my table view cells with the texts from my NSArray list and I want to do the same with my audios. 
I would like to know how it is possible to play specific audio when specific cell row is tapped and when the other cell is pressed, to stop playing audio from previous cell. I've tried to search populating table view cells with audio files, but I did not find any results. 
Also I don't know whether I need to add button for playing audio in my prototype cell, or I can play audio by simply tapping the cell without inserting button on it. 
I am not really sure which audio framework is correct in my case. 
Please share your opinions and if it is possible for you, please demonstrate with the objective-c code examples. 
And sorry for any typos and my text structure. (As i am writing on my phone at 2 a.m.).

Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

**try this :** if u got any issues comment below .

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"%@",selectedCell.textLabel.text);



        AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

        NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [yourSoundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
        NSError *audioError = [[NSError alloc] init];
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];

        if (!audioError) {
            [audioPlayer play];
            NSLog(@"playing!");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error!");
        }


        }
```

Comment: use  #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> frame work